# Autolayout needed if only support one orientation?

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout

Is Autolayout needed to setup for any subview, if my application **only support one orientation** (e.g., landscape right), applied for all UIViewControllers?

Yes, of course in the case of using animation I agree. But for the normal case, do I need AutoLayout?

Note: I am using XCode7, Swift, ios9

Answer (score 5):

[Understanding Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html)

> Auto Layout dynamically calculates the size and position of all the
>   views in your view hierarchy, based on constraints placed on those
>   views. For example, you can constrain a button so that it is
>   horizontally centered with an Image view and so that the button’s top
>   edge always remains 8 points below the image’s bottom. If the image
>   view’s size or position changes, the button’s position automatically
>   adjusts to match.
>
> This constraint-based approach to design allows you to build user
>   interfaces that dynamically respond to both internal and external
>   changes.

Unless you are making an app for one specific screen size, you will want to 
use Auto Layout.

Use cases:

1. You want to support different size classes.
2. You want to support different screen sizes.
3. The content displayed by the app changes.
4. The app supports internationalization.
5. The app supports Dynamic Type (iOS).

> Most of these changes can occur at runtime, and they require a dynamic
>   response from your app. Others, like support for different screen
>   sizes, represent the app adapting to different environments. Even
>   through the screen size won’t typically change at runtime, creating an
>   adaptive interface lets your app run equally well on an iPhone 4S, an
>   iPhone 6 Plus, or even an iPad. Auto Layout is also a key component
>   for supporting Slide Over and Split Views on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Auto layout is not required at all. Even for multiple orientations.

However, If you don't use it, you'll have to manage placement for all the different sized devices yourself. So you might as well use it.